# TransactionScope and Error: ORA-02049

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, ora-02049

I have the following routine:

```
For j = 1 To NumItems
    dbValueLookup.Load(j)
    Using scope As New TransactionScope()
        For i = firstIndex To lastIndex

            'dbValueLookup is basically just a Dictionary of items already in the DB
            If dbValueLookup.ContainsKey(i) Then
                'updateData is a subroutine that updates this row with new data
                updateData(j,i)
                rowsUpdated = rowsUpdated + 1
                dbValueLookup.Remove(i)
            Else
                'updateData is a subroutine that adds a new row to DB
                addData(j,i)
                rowsAdded = rowsAdded + 1
            End If
        Next

        If dbValueLookup.Count = 0 Then
            'This commits the transaction - records will be updated when End Using is reached
            scope.Complete()
            If rowsAdded + rowsUpdated > 0 Then
                ShowMessage("Records Updated: " + rowsUpdated.ToString() + " Records Added: " + rowsAdded.ToString())
            End If

        Else
            'We are left with data from the database that was not updated.  This is a problem, so we don't "Complete" the scope.
            'This will result in a rollback.
            ShowWarningMessage("Incomplete Data for " + i.ToString())
        End If
    End Using
Next
```

Running this against both our production and test Oracle 11g database sporadically (or if there is a pattern, I haven't found it yet) generates the Oracle Error:
 ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

Since this is the only process running against the test database, there shouldn't be any issue with different users competing for a lock.

Any ideas what might be causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you must have two transactions competing for a row lock.

Just brainstorming here, but if `dbValueLookup.Count = 0`, then you will call `addData` (which sounds like it does an `INSERT`?), but you will not call `scope.Complete()` to commit your transaction.

I'm not sure if the `End Using` will always commit the transaction or not.

Do you really need to create the `TransactionScope` on every iteration of the loop? Why not create one transaction, do all your updates/inserts, then commit once?